# how to make rows into column using pivot

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

i have an date like this

```
Name              VALUE
ClientID     M01010001250
InterviewType   1
InterviewDate   7/8/2011
ClientID    M01010001260
InterviewType   1
InterviewDate   7/8/2011
ClientID    M01010001260
InterviewType   5
InterviewDate   1869-07-01
ClientID    M01010001290
InterviewType   1
InterviewDate   7/8/2011
```

now my out put should be like this

```
SEQ   ClientID  InterviewType   InterviewDate
1   M01100016550    5   9/9/2011
2   M01100016550    5   9/9/2011
3   M01030000680    5   9/9/2011
```

i have written a query using pivot :

```
SELECT SEQ,ClientID,InterviewType,InterviewDate
FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME,VALUE ORDER BY NAME,VALUE) AS SEQ,NAME,VALUE
FROM Table1) DT
PIVOT (MAX(VALUE)FOR NAME IN(ClientID,InterviewType,InterviewDate))DT1
ORDER BY SEQ
```

even though i am using row_number it is not giving desired output suggest me

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is to group all the rows in three. I have a working solutions :

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY orderby) AS SEQ,
          NAME,
          VALUE
  FROM    (
            select  1 as orderby, 
                    * 
            from Table1 
          )t
 )

SELECT SEQ,
       ClientID,
       InterviewType,
       InterviewDate
FROM   (
          SELECT  ((SEQ-1)/3)+1 AS SEQ,
                  NAME,
                  VALUE
          FROM    MyCTE
       ) DT
PIVOT  ( 
          MAX(VALUE)
          FOR NAME 
          IN(ClientID,InterviewType,InterviewDate)
        )DT1
ORDER BY SEQ
```

You may find an [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bdcce/14)

Answer (score 0):

Your query isn't working because it's numbering the rows based on their value, so regardless of the order they go in, the rows with the lowest values will be first.  Your row which has InterviewType 5 will always have the highest rownumber if the other rows all have InterviewType =1.

Without a way to uniquely identify which entries are supposed to go together, the order returned from queries in SQL server isn't guaranteed.  However, if your data is in that exact format mentioned above - so the rows are always in the format ClientId, then InterviewType then InterviewDate, the following should work.

```
select  p.*
from    (select *,
        CEILING((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1) / 3) as [Row]
        from    Table1 t) t
PIVOT (max(value) for name in (ClientID, InterviewType, InterviewDate)) p
```

Output on my test data:

```
 0  M01050001250    16  7/8/2011
 1  M01010001260    1   7/8/2011
 2  M01010001260    5   1869-07-01
 3  M01010001290    1   7/8/2011
```

(The ceiling function is numbering every three rows - first three are 0, then the next three are 1, etc.)

Comment: This has been asked 27 mins ago, and we gave the answers with 9 seconds difference....!!! :) You got first, though...